# Kendo UI Grid and composed column

Tags: xml, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I bind Kendo UI grid to datasource populated with xml.

It works for me.

Now I want to pupulate a cell of each row with 'n' multiple values, comma separated, of a nested node.

Example of xml file:

```
<product id="1">
 Microsoft Office
 <tags><tag>microsoft</tag></tags>
 </product>
<product id="1">
 Ububtu Linux
 <tags><tag>Canonical</tag><tag>OS</tag><tag>Open Source</tag></tags>
 </product>
 <product id="1">
  Windows 8
  <tags><tag>microsoft</tag><tag>OS</tag></tags>
 </product>
 </product>
```

The result I want:

```
ID     Product              Tags

1      Microsoft Office     microsoft
2      Ubuntu Linux         canonical, OS, Open Source
3      Windows 8            microsoft, OS
```

For first 2 columns there's no problem:

```
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            type: "xml",
            transport: {
                read: { url: 'some_remote_xml',
                    dataType: "xml"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                type: "xml",
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        id: { field: 'product/@id', type: "number" },
                        Product: { field: 'product/text()', type: "string" } 

                    }
```

How can i render the 'Tags' column??

Any help will be appreciate!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one of two ways:

1) provide a "row template", which is demonstrated here: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/rowtemplate.html

Or

2) You can use a custom `template` for your column settings in the grid.

For the custom template, you'll need to list all of your columns that you want in the grid, and then provide the `template` setting for the column that should display the custom information.

The easiest way to do this would be to set the `template` to a function, which receives the current data row as a parameter. Then you can `.join` the tags with a `,` and return that.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: {
    // ... your data source here
  },

  columns: [
    {field: "id", title: "Product ID"},
    {field: "product", title: "Product Name"},
    {
      title: "Tags",
      template: function(dataRow){
        return dataRow.tags.join(", ");
      }
  ]
});
```

There is likely a better way to get this done using KendoUI's templating engine, but this will at least get your comma-delimited list of items displayed for now.

You can read about column templates, here: http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.template

Comment: It can also be solved using `schema.parse` and create a _virtual_ column with the content of merging the `Tags`.

Comment: would love to see an example of that posted as an answer :)

Comment: Are you challenging me? :-) Is it because it is not possible or for question of completeness?

Comment: LOL :) more of a "Oh! I didn't know that!" response, and I really would like to see an example of it. I haven't used schema.parse... didn't even know it was there, sadly :P

Comment: I'm pretty lazy! Lets say that I do it in JSON (because I have a lot of code snippets that I can reuse) or, please, provide me some example in XML and I'll modify it, Deal?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28117/discussion-between-onabai-and-derick-bailey)

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Derik and OnaBai.

I know that the solution can pass from kind of Kendo Template... but the difficulty was to implement solution like that.

The real code of my application have a lot of complexity.

In the example above wi will manage not only the 'tag' node, but attributes, etc....

Something like:

```
  <tags>
   <tag id="1">First tag</tag>
   <tag id="2">Second tag</tag>
   ...
  </tags>
```

If this fragment in the schema part return the product id (the xml id attribute of a product):

```
id: { field: 'product/@id', type: "number" }
```

... and this return the product text (the xml text node):

```
Product: { field: 'product/text()', type: "string" }
```

How can I manage in a template one or more tags returned??

```
Tags: { field: 'product/tags' }
```

I must to implement a template that manage the array of 'tag' child nodes.

Ok.

I've found this solution:

Template definition for the column:

```
 //pass the 'Tags' array to a javascript function
 template: '#= myfunction(Tags) #'
```

... and then a global javascript function:

```
function myfunction(e) {
var result = '';

//iteration on the 'tags' array
for (var i = 0; i < e.length ; i++) {
    result += '<a href="' + e[i]["@id"] + '">' + e[i]["#text"] + '</a>';

}
return result;  // now in the tags column of the grid we have the 'tags/tag' xml section   of each product, rendered as html anchor

}
```

It works great!!!

I hope this help other friends.

If you think better or mutch easier solutions you're welcome ;-))